# How do I write scraped lines in txt and check for duplicate before it writes in Python?

Tags: python, duplicates

1. I am scraping from user channel id's they public information emails based on my keywords but some channels id's repeat and then also emails repeat too while scraping large amount of channel id's, so before I write them line by line to my text I need they check also for possible duplicate email and ignore if email already exist in text file.
2. Also I would be graceful if you write me there how to remove emptyspaces because I already have code which sometimes works other not works and somehow it writes the empty line with space.

**My Code which writes line by line all emails:**

```
with open("scraped_emails.txt", 'a') as f:
            for email in cleanEmail:
                f.write(email.replace(" ", "")+ '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an `if` statement to check if the email you want to append is already in the file or not, by doing :

```
cleanEmail = ['a@b.com', '   glennbz@veriznon.net    ', 'x@yy.ul']

with open("scraped_emails.txt", 'r+') as f:
    emails = f.read()
    for email in cleanEmail:
        if email not in emails:
            f.write(email.strip() + '\n')
```

Note that I added the `strip()` method, and this will solve your empty spaces problem by removing both leading and trailing white spaces.

```
# Output 
a@b.com
glenjnnbz@veriznon.net
x@yy.ul
```

Comment: it doesnt work mate because if my code will loop over and over it will not listen so it is frustrating

Comment: Didn't understand well. Even you loop through it over and over, always it will pass by the checking phase, maybe something isn't right in other place in your code, can you explain more

Comment: I have asked another question I think my code loop forever that's why it doesn't respect number of links in text file and keep writing the same emails but even through your code doesn't work well only it removes white space but if even my code loop it should remove already written duplicated email which does not

Comment: Yes the file will still contains the previous duplicated emails and whitespaces. As mentioned in your question you want to remove the whitespaces and check if an email already exist in the file before writing it, that's the solution I delivered do.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to clean up your file `scraped_emails.txt`, remove duplicates and correct the emails by removing whitespace?
I would do two steps:

1. parse all your emails from `scraped_emails.txt`, strip the spaces and store them in a set (unique)
2. overwrite your existing file with the cleaned-up values. If you are unsure about this, write to a different file first and check the results

```
clean_emails = set()
file_name = "scraped_emails.txt"

# initial reading of emails
print(f"Reading {file_name} to clean emails ..")
initial_line_counter = 0
with open(file_name, "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        # remember input lines, just for statistics
        initial_line_counter += 1

        # strips newlines and whitespaces
        cleaned_email = line.rstrip("\n").strip()
        
        # you mentioned empty lines - this prevents adding of empty strings to your set
        if cleaned_email:
            clean_emails.add(cleaned_email)

# opening the file with the attribute mode="w" overwrites existing files
with open(file_name, "w") as f_out:
    for email in clean_emails:
        f_out.write(f"{email}\n")

print(f"Reduced {initial_line_counter} to {len(clean_emails)} cleaned email addresses")
```

You can test this with a `scraped_emails.txt` with the following content:

```
some_mail1@yahoo.com
some_mail2@yahoo.com
some_mail3@yahoo.com
some_mail4@yahoo.com
some_mail5@yahoo.com
some_mail6@yahoo.com
   some_mail@y7ahoo.com  

some_mail8@yahoo.com  
some_mail9@yahoo.com
some_mail9@yahoo.com
some_mail9@yahoo.com
```

Comment: thx for passing by, but I have a scraper which f.write scraped email in text file so I need it in my function not create another one, so what I need is WHiLE he is scraping emails before IT WRITE new line he check if same email not already in text and if not then it write and save and continue, because the scraper will check many response contents so it needs to be written during the function

Comment: in SHORT I need to get rid of duplicate emails to not write it in the text scraped_emails.txt while it is scraping

Comment: You would have to read your existing emails into memory to be able to check them before writing new emails to the file, unfortunately

Comment: any tutorial on this topic? since Im not able even to google this function cant find the words

Comment: you simply use the first part of my script, and before writing any new email addresses to your file after scraping, you clean up your newly received email and check if its in the set already - if so,  you continue. Something like `cleaned_email=line.rstrip("\n").strip()` and `if cleaned_email in clean_emails: continue`.

Comment: it still write duplicate :-(

Comment: I have a class to remove duplicate but I wanted something what will use on 'fly' to write only unique emails strings but maybe it is not possible